# Decomposition into Simple Elements

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm Nina. I have a really tough homework that counts as a test and I couldn't do it. It's really urgent. Help please!

1. Let $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}^+$. Let $F$ be the function defined in $\Bbb{R}$ by
   $$F(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh\alpha - \cos x}.$$
   What is the decomposition into simple elements of the fraction?
   $$ -\frac{2X}{X^2 - (e^{\alpha}+ e^{-\alpha} )X+1} $$
2. Give an other expression for $\displaystyle -\frac{e^{\alpha}}{e^{ix} - e^{\alpha}}$.
3. And for $\displaystyle -\frac{e^{\alpha}}{e^{ix} - e^{-\alpha}}$.

And big thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use notations for $cosh(x)=cos(i*x)$

$cosh(x)=cos(-i*x)$

$cosh(x)=(1/2)*(e^{-x}+e^x)$

EDITED: for $2$ and $3$ ,you  divide both side by $e^a$ because $e^a$  never equal to $0$
also note that  $(1/2)*(e^a+e^{-a})=cosh(a)$;if you divide both side by $2$ you get

$X/((x^2)/2-(1/2)*(e^a+e^{-a})*x+1/2)$.which is equal to

$X/(X^2/2-cosh(a)*X+1/2)$

Comment: @Nina i hope this  will help